# Why won't my submit button do anything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a form here and when i press the button, i get no output in the console. I added the whole form below. I am not the original writer for this form, I am just trying to add a feature to edit the subject on this form.

View:

```
      <%= form_tag :action => 'update_subject', :controller => 'task', :id => @task.id do -%>
  <tr>

    <td><b>Subject:</b></td>
    <td><div id='edit_subject_div'><%=text_field_tag 'subject', @task.subject %></div></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><%=submit_tag "Submit", data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."}%></td>
   </tr>
   <%end -%>
```

Action:

```
  def update_subject
    @task = Task.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @task.subject != params[:subject]
      @task.subject = params[:subject]
      @task.save!
    end
  end
```

Whole Form:

```
    <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#activity_category_id').chained('select#cat_type_id');
    $('#activity_category_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
    $('#activity_location_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
    $('#activity_location_modifier_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
    //$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
  });
  $(document).on('ajax:before', function(){
    $.facebox.loading();
  });

</script>
<h2>Task Detail:</h2><br/>
<%
   @task = Task.find(params[:task_id].to_i) if params[:task_id]
   @devices = [["",""]] + Device.where(job_id: @task.job_id, active: true).order(:name).pluck('name', 'id')
    @hours = (0..24).to_a
    @minutes = [0, 15, 30, 45]
    @today = Date.today
    @priorities = ["High", "Medium", "Low"]
   @user_list=[["",""]] + User.where(:active=>true).order('nickname').pluck('nickname', 'id')
   @groups=Group.order('name').pluck('name', 'id')
   @groups=@groups.each do |g| g[1]='group' + g[1].to_s end
   @users = @user_list + @groups
   @location=Location.where(active: true).order('description').pluck('description', 'id')
   @location_modifier=LocationModifier.where(active: true).order('description').pluck('description', 'id')
   #@categories = Category.where(active: 1).order(:description).pluck('description', 'id')
    params[:sort].nil? ? sort_str = "" : sort_str = params[:sort]
    params[:hist_length].nil? ? hist_str = "" : hist_str = params[:hist_length]
    @return_url = params[:return_url]
%>


<table style="border:none;width:90%">
<tr><td style="width:38%;vertical-align: top">
<table style="border:none;width:90%">
  <tr><td><b>Task ID:</b></td>
    <td><%=@task.id.to_s%></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Method of Contact:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.contact_type %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Contacted by:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.customer_contact %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Task Created by:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.created_by.nickname %></td>
  </tr>
<% if !@task.parent_task_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Task Split from:</b></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Parent Task', :action => 'edit', :id => @task.parent_task_id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  <%= form_for @task do |f|%>
  <tr>

    <td><b><%= f.label :subject %>:</b></td>
    <td><div id='edit_subject_div'><%= f.text_field :subject %></div></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
     <td></td>
     <td><%= f.submit %></td>
   </tr>
   <%end %>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>Description:</b></td>
  </tr>c

  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><%=simple_format(@task.description)%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Task Initiated:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.created_at.strftime("%H:%M %p %m/%d/%y") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= (Date.today - @task.problem_on).to_i %> Days Old</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Assigned Due Date:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.due_on.strftime("%m/%d/%y")  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Status:</b></td>
    <td>
    <% if @task.resolved_on %>
    Resolved on <%= @task.resolved_on.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
    <% elsif @today < @task.due_on %>
    Due in <%= (@task.due_on - @today).to_i %> Days
    <% elsif @today > @task.due_on %>
    <%= (@today - @task.due_on).to_i %> Days Overdue
    <% else %>
    Due Today
    <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><b>Device:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.device.nil? ? "None Assigned" : @task.device.name %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Assigned To:</b></td>
    <% if !@task.assigned_to.nil? then %>
    <td><%=@task.assigned_to.nickname %></td>
    <% elsif !@task.group.nil? then %>
    <td><%=@task.group.name%></td>
    <% else %>
    <td>Unassigned</td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Priority:</b></td>
    <td><%=@task.priority %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Resolved:</b></td>
    <% if !@task.resolved_on.nil? then %>
    <td><%=@task.resolved_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td>Unresolved</td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>
<%=form_tag :action => 'update', :controller => 'task', :id => @task.id do -%><%=hidden_field_tag 'from_project_track', 'yes'%><%=hidden_field_tag 'return_path', @return_url%>
<table>
  <tr><td colspan=2><b>New Note:</b></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><%= text_area_tag 'note', nil,  :size => '50x5' %></td>
  </tr>
   <% if !@task.device_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_device_id">Device</label>:</td>
    <td><%=select_tag 'task[device_id]', options_for_select(@devices, @task.device_id) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <%else%>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_device_id">Device</label>:</td>
    <td><%=select_tag 'task[device_id]', options_for_select(@devices, '') %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
    <td>Assigned Due Date:</td>
    <td><%= date_select 'task', 'due_on'  %></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% if !@task.assigned_to_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>:</td>
    <td><%= select_tag 'task[assigned_to_id]', options_for_select(@users, :selected=>@task.assigned_to_id.to_s) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% elsif !@task.group_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>:</td>
    <td><%= select_tag 'task[assigned_to_id]', options_for_select(@users, 'group' + @task.group_id.to_s) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% else %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>:</td>
    <td><%= select_tag 'task[assigned_to_id]', options_for_select(@users) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="task_priority">Priority:</label></td>
    <td><%= select 'task', 'priority', @priorities  %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Resolved:</td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'resolved', 1, @task.resolved_on %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Bill:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= select_tag 'bill_hours', options_for_select(@hours, 0)  %>:<%= select_tag 'bill_minutes', options_for_select(@minutes, 0)  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nonbill:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= select_tag 'nonbill_hours', options_for_select(@hours, 0)  %>:<%= select_tag 'nonbill_minutes', options_for_select(@minutes, 0)  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <%=select_tag 'cat_type_id',options_for_select(@cat_type_list,@selected_cat_type), {:prompt=>"Select Category Type"}%><br/>
      <select id="activity_category_id" prompt="Select Category" name="activity[category_id]" style="width:300px;">
        <option value=''>Select Category</option>
        <%@cat_list.each do |c|%>
            <option value="<%=c.id%>" <%=(!@activity.nil? && @activity.category_id==c.id) ? "selected" : "" %> class="<%=c.cat_type_id.nil? ? '':c.cat_type_id%>"><%=c.short_description.nil? ? c.description : c.short_description%></option>
        <%end%>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location:</td>
    <td><%= select 'activity', 'location_id',[["",""]] + @location %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location Modifier:</td>
    <td><%= select 'activity', 'location_modifier_id',[["",""]] + @location_modifier %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Review?:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= check_box 'activity', 'review' %></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 align="CENTER"><%=submit_tag "Submit", id: 'commit', data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."}%></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end -%>

</td>
<% if params[:mobile] == "1" then %>
</tr>
<tr>
<% end %>
<td valign="TOP">
<table style="width:90%;padding:0;">
<tr><td colspan="2" ><%=link_to 'Task Time Report', :controller=>'time', :action=>'list', :task_id=>@task.id %></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="LEFT"><b>Notes:</b></td></tr>
<% @notes = Note.where(task_id: @task.id).order('created_at') %>
<% @notes.each do |n| %>
<tr style="background-color: <%=cycle("white","silver")%>;"><td valign="TOP"><b><%=n.created_by.nil? ? "Error" : n.created_by.nickname %><br>(<%=n.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M")%>)</b></td><td valign="TOP"><%=simple_format(n.content)%></td></tr>
<% end %>
</table>


</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you have valid record for that controller action in your config/routes.rb?

Comment: yes   post 'task/update_subject'

Comment: have you put a debugger breakpoint in your `update_subject` action to see if it stopped there?\

Comment: Also why are you using `form_tag` instead of `form_for` since it's a form for an object in your db

Comment: yes i tried putting byebug at the first line in the action and it did not stop.

Comment: Please show the logs for the `task`update_subject` action.

Comment: @MichaelGaskill I am fairly new to RoR, I am coming from a ASP.NET environment. I am using Ubuntu with RubyMine as my IDE, where can i get the log file? If your talking about the console, there is no output when pressed.

Comment: It would be the console and in `log/development.log`.  If you're not getting anything in the log, that's something useful to know.

Comment: yes, development.log does not add anything when this butting is pressed.

Comment: There is a bunch of logic in your Views. I strongly suggest you move that away from the view to the API layer

Comment: Your submit action is calling `confirmSelections` in your Javascript code.  Have you confirmed that all of the conditions in that code are satisfied to be able to submit the form?

Comment: yes, i have. also, there are two forms on this page.

Comment: moving the logic to the controller is on my todo list, Just haven't got to it yet. I am new to this project and the code isn't written by me.

Comment: i have removed the JS validation logic, same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Sure why or how this fixed it but i removed the first form and made the second form cover the whole view. The downside to this is I have to submit the whole page in order to update the subject.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('select#activity_category_id').chained('select#cat_type_id');
    $('#activity_category_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
    $('#activity_location_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
    $('#activity_location_modifier_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
    //$('a[rel*=facebox]').facebox();
  });
  $(document).on('ajax:before', function(){
    $.facebox.loading();
  });
  function confirmSelections(){
    valid=false;
    valid1=false;
    valid2=false;
    if ($('#activity_category_id').val()==""){
      $('#activity_category_id').css('border', 'red 2px solid');
      valid= false;
    }else{
      $('#activity_category_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
      valid= true;
    }
    if ($('#activity_location_id').val()=="")
    {
      $('#activity_location_id').css('border', 'red 2px solid');
      valid1=false;
    }
    else
    {$('#activity_location_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
      valid1=true;}
    if ($('#activity_location_modifier_id').val()=="")
    {$('#activity_location_modifier_id').css('border', 'red 2px solid');
      valid2=false;
    }else{
      $('#activity_location_modifier_id').css('border', 'Silver 1px solid');
      valid2= true;
    }
    if (valid && valid1 && valid2)
    {return true;}
    else
    {
      if (($('#nonbill_hours').val()!='0' || $('#bill_hours').val()!='0' || $('#nonbill_minutes').val()!='0' || $('#bill_minutes').val()!='0' || $('#nonbill_hours').val()!='0') && ($('#activity_category_id').val()=='')){
        var answer = (confirm('No category is selected. Click Cancel to select. Click OK to update the task with no time entry.')) ;
        return answer;
      }
      if (($('#nonbill_hours').val()!='0' || $('#bill_hours').val()!='0' || $('#nonbill_minutes').val()!='0' || $('#bill_minutes').val()!='0' || $('#nonbill_hours').val()!='0') && ($('#activity_location_id').val()=='')){
        var answer = (confirm('No location is selected. Click Cancel to select. Click OK to update the task with no time entry.')) ;
        return answer;
      }
      if (($('#nonbill_hours').val()!='0' || $('#bill_hours').val()!='0' || $('#nonbill_minutes').val()!='0' || $('#bill_minutes').val()!='0' || $('#nonbill_hours').val()!='0') && ($('#activity_location_modifier_id').val()=='')){
        var answer = (confirm('No location modifier is selected. Click Cancel to select. Click OK to update the task with no time entry.')) ;
        return answer;
      }
    }
  }
  $('form').submit(confirmSelections);
</script>
<h2>Task Detail:</h2><br/>
<%
   @task = Task.find(params[:task_id].to_i) if params[:task_id]
   @devices = [["",""]] + Device.where(job_id: @task.job_id, active: true).order(:name).pluck('name', 'id')
    @hours = (0..24).to_a
    @minutes = [0, 15, 30, 45]
    @today = Date.today
    @priorities = ["High", "Medium", "Low"]
   @user_list=[["",""]] + User.where(:active=>true).order('nickname').pluck('nickname', 'id')
   @groups=Group.order('name').pluck('name', 'id')
   @groups=@groups.each do |g| g[1]='group' + g[1].to_s end
   @users = @user_list + @groups
   @location=Location.where(active: true).order('description').pluck('description', 'id')
   @location_modifier=LocationModifier.where(active: true).order('description').pluck('description', 'id')
   #@categories = Category.where(active: 1).order(:description).pluck('description', 'id')
    params[:sort].nil? ? sort_str = "" : sort_str = params[:sort]
    params[:hist_length].nil? ? hist_str = "" : hist_str = params[:hist_length]
    @return_url = params[:return_url]
%>


<table style="border:none;width:90%">
<tr><td style="width:38%;vertical-align: top">
  <%=form_tag :action => 'update', :controller => 'task', :id => @task.id do -%><%=hidden_field_tag 'from_project_track', 'yes'%><%=hidden_field_tag 'return_path', @return_url%>
<table style="border:none;width:90%">
  <tr><td><b>Task ID:</b></td>
    <td><%=@task.id.to_s%></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Method of Contact:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.contact_type %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Contacted by:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.customer_contact %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Task Created by:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.created_by.nickname %></td>
  </tr>
<% if !@task.parent_task_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Task Split from:</b></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Parent Task', :action => 'edit', :id => @task.parent_task_id %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Subject:</b></td>
    <td><div id='edit_subject_div'><%= text_field_tag 'task[subject]', @task.subject%></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><b>Description:</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><%=simple_format(@task.description)%></td>
  </tr>
  <tr><td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Task Initiated:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.created_at.strftime("%H:%M %p %m/%d/%y") %>&nbsp;&nbsp;<%= (Date.today - @task.problem_on).to_i %> Days Old</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Assigned Due Date:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.due_on.strftime("%m/%d/%y")  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Status:</b></td>
    <td>
    <% if @task.resolved_on %>
    Resolved on <%= @task.resolved_on.strftime("%m/%d/%y") %>
    <% elsif @today < @task.due_on %>
    Due in <%= (@task.due_on - @today).to_i %> Days
    <% elsif @today > @task.due_on %>
    <%= (@today - @task.due_on).to_i %> Days Overdue
    <% else %>
    Due Today
    <% end %>
    </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><b>Device:</b></td>
    <td><%= @task.device.nil? ? "None Assigned" : @task.device.name %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Assigned To:</b></td>
    <% if !@task.assigned_to.nil? then %>
    <td><%=@task.assigned_to.nickname %></td>
    <% elsif !@task.group.nil? then %>
    <td><%=@task.group.name%></td>
    <% else %>
    <td>Unassigned</td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Priority:</b></td>
    <td><%=@task.priority %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><b>Resolved:</b></td>
    <% if !@task.resolved_on.nil? then %>
    <td><%=@task.resolved_on.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") %></td>
    <% else %>
    <td>Unresolved</td>
    <% end %>
  </tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td colspan=2><b>New Note:</b></td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan=2><%= text_area_tag 'note', nil,  :size => '50x5' %></td>
  </tr>
   <% if !@task.device_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_device_id">Device</label>:</td>
    <td><%=select_tag 'task[device_id]', options_for_select(@devices, @task.device_id) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <%else%>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_device_id">Device</label>:</td>
    <td><%=select_tag 'task[device_id]', options_for_select(@devices, '') %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <tr>
    <td>Assigned Due Date:</td>
    <td><%= date_select 'task', 'due_on'  %></td>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% if !@task.assigned_to_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>:</td>
    <td><%= select_tag 'task[assigned_to_id]', options_for_select(@users, :selected=>@task.assigned_to_id.to_s) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% elsif !@task.group_id.nil? then %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>:</td>
    <td><%= select_tag 'task[assigned_to_id]', options_for_select(@users, 'group' + @task.group_id.to_s) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% else %>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="task_assigned_to">Assigned To</label>:</td>
    <td><%= select_tag 'task[assigned_to_id]', options_for_select(@users) %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
    <% end %>
    <tr>
    <td><label for="task_priority">Priority:</label></td>
    <td><%= select 'task', 'priority', @priorities  %></td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Resolved:</td>
    <td><%= check_box_tag 'resolved', 1, @task.resolved_on %></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Bill:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= select_tag 'bill_hours', options_for_select(@hours, 0)  %>:<%= select_tag 'bill_minutes', options_for_select(@minutes, 0)  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Nonbill:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= select_tag 'nonbill_hours', options_for_select(@hours, 0)  %>:<%= select_tag 'nonbill_minutes', options_for_select(@minutes, 0)  %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Category:</td>
    <td colspan="2">
      <%=select_tag 'cat_type_id',options_for_select(@cat_type_list,@selected_cat_type), {:prompt=>"Select Category Type"}%><br/>
      <select id="activity_category_id" prompt="Select Category" name="activity[category_id]" style="width:300px;">
        <option value=''>Select Category</option>
        <%@cat_list.each do |c|%>
            <option value="<%=c.id%>" <%=(!@activity.nil? && @activity.category_id==c.id) ? "selected" : "" %> class="<%=c.cat_type_id.nil? ? '':c.cat_type_id%>"><%=c.short_description.nil? ? c.description : c.short_description%></option>
        <%end%>
      </select></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location:</td>
    <td><%= select 'activity', 'location_id',[["",""]] + @location %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Location Modifier:</td>
    <td><%= select 'activity', 'location_modifier_id',[["",""]] + @location_modifier %></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Review?:</td>
    <td colspan="2"><%= check_box 'activity', 'review' %></td>
  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td colspan=2 align="CENTER"><%=submit_tag "Submit", id: 'commit', data: { disable_with: "Please wait..."}%></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<% end -%>

</td>
<% if params[:mobile] == "1" then %>
</tr>
<tr>
<% end %>
<td valign="TOP">
<table style="width:90%;padding:0;">
<tr><td colspan="2" ><%=link_to 'Task Time Report', :controller=>'time', :action=>'list', :task_id=>@task.id %></td></tr>
<tr><td colspan="2" align="LEFT"><b>Notes:</b></td></tr>
<% @notes = Note.where(task_id: @task.id).order('created_at') %>
<% @notes.each do |n| %>
<tr style="background-color: <%=cycle("white","silver")%>;"><td valign="TOP"><b><%=n.created_by.nil? ? "Error" : n.created_by.nickname %><br>(<%=n.created_at.strftime("%m/%d/%Y %I:%M")%>)</b></td><td valign="TOP"><%=simple_format(n.content)%></td></tr>
<% end %>
</table>


</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `form_for` since you are modifying an existing object `@task`:

```
<%= form_for :task, @task, :url => { :action => :update_subject} do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :subject %>:
  <%= f.text_field :subject %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: okay, made the changes, the button still doesnt produce a output to the console or update the item.

Comment: hmmmm strange... maybe it's something with your html. could you past in the whole form with html

Comment: `form_for` is definitely the way to go since you are using it for a specific modal ( `Task` )

Comment: i added the whole form above

Comment: Cool. You have a bunch of Javascript there. Did you try submitting the form while looking at the browser console to see if any js related errors appear ?

Comment: yes, there are no JS errors or warnings when the button is pressed

Comment: i have removed the JS validation logic, same result.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following line from the Javascript:

```
$('form').submit(confirmSelections);
```

This will no longer perform dynamic form validations, but should allow the `Submit` button to work.  The real issue will be somewhere in the `confirmSelections` logic, and that will be dependent on what data has been entered on the form.

As a side note, this code looks like it would need some serious rework.  At a minimum:

- Use `form_for` instead of `form_tag`
- Use `f.submit` instead of `submit_tag` (once the form_for is implemented)
- All of the Javascript is static, and should be moved into the assets pipeline, rather than be included inline
- All of the Ruby code in the block immediately following `<h2>Task Detail:</h2>` should be moved to the controller/action
- The code for `@notes = Note.where(task_id: @task.id).order('created_at')` should be moved to the controller/action
- The Javascript should select CSS classes, not explicit CSS styling, so that your presentation is able to be easily maintained

These should actually help make this template reasonably maintainable and separate the MVC concerns from one another.

Comment: i removed all that validation an updated the code above, still same result.

Comment: You might check to see if there are any event handlers registered in the asset pipeline that might be handling events for the form or the submit button.  I would grep that code for the IDs of both the form and the submit button.  However, if the events are registered on the class or element type, that might be more difficult to find.